# "Fax it to me at number" versus "fax it to me to number"

Tags: phrase-usage

The phrase people use when they want others to email or call them is "Please call/email me **at** […]." It got me thinking about faxing.

Since fax numbers are like phone numbers, do you say, "please fax it to me **at** number xxx-xxx-xxxx" or "please fax it to me **to number** xxx-xxx-xxxx"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In US usage there's a **simple rule**: use *to* with either the recipient or the address, unless both recipient and address are specified, in which case use *at* with the address

Fax/mail/email/telegraph/send/dispatch a communication

1. **To** the recipient, *or*
2. **To** the address, *or*
3. **To** the recipient **at** the address.

Even if your syntax permits you to reduce the recipient phrase to a bare pronoun, without the *to*, retain *at* for the address. Using *to* gives the sentence a faintly 16th-century ring.

> Fax me your answer ASAP at 555-555-5555.
>   <sup>?</sup> Fax me your answer ASAP to 555-555-5555.

Comment: Personally, I don't see why *fax* should be any different to *call, ring, phone, contact, etc.*. I'd tend to use **on** for all of them, but I think that may be a predominantly British usage.

Comment: @Fumblefingers That's very interesting. I don't think I've ever encountered "Call me on ###-####"; in US usage it's almost always "at", and "on" would be used only with a message board of some sort: "You can reach me on Basecamp" or "You can ping me on ELL". I'll modify to say it's US usage.

Comment: Unless you want to make "fax" a special case (for no good reason that I can see), I think usage in other contexts was quite well covered by [this ELU answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55778/2637) to a related question.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those areas where more than one preposition could probably be used.

If I were using *to*, I'd probably leave out the *to me*:

> *Please fax it to xxx-xxx-xxxx*.

If I wanted to leave in the *to me*, I'd probably use *at*:

> *Please fax it to me at xxx-xxx-xxxx*.

Using a Google books search, I found instances of both in literature:

> Please place this questionnaire in the self-addressed return envelope to be mailed or fax it to xxx-xxx-xxxx today.
>
> If you have a topic you would like us to include in our interactive general session, fax it to me at xxx-xxx-xxxx.

Comment: Could you say: "Fax me at xxx-xxx-xxxx?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA: [Sure you could](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22fax%20me%20at%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1985,cd_max:2007&lr=lang_en).